# CSS: Calculating in ems: font-size inside font-size?

Tags: css, font-size

My current project is entirely based on ems.

**html**

```
<div class="tiny">
    This is some tiny text which is tiny.
</div>

<div class="small">
    This is some small text which is small.
    <div class="tiny">
        And this is some tiny text inside small text which should be as tiny as the other tiny one.
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.tiny {
    font-size:0.7em;
    line-height:1.7;   
}

.small {
    font-size:0.8em;
    line-height:1.3em;  
}
```

In this case the `tiny` text inside the `small` text is smaller than the normal `tiny` text.

First off, why is that? Secondly, how can I fix this or make it the same size?

http://jsfiddle.net/DFKtF/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since you tagged your question [css3], you can use `rem` instead so it is always relative to the font size of the root element, and not the parent element. Of course, browser support isn't that great and all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `em` unit mostly denotes the font size of the element itself, but in the value of `font-size` (where that would make no sense), it denotes the font size of the parent element. So in your example, the quantity `0.7em` means 0.7 times the font size of the enclosing element, which already has a reduced font size.

To deal with this, simply select the number accordingly. If you want tiny text that is 0.7 times the copy text font size, and the enclosing element has font size of 0.8 times the copy text size, you’ll need the number 0.7/0.8, i.e. `.small` should have `font-size:0.875em`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `em`, use `px`. Or carefully calculate. When used to specify font sizes, the `em` unit refers to the font size of the parent element.

Comment: Recommending `px` as a solution when someone is doing the right thing, using `em`, and needs help with *that*.

Comment: I said "or carefully calculate", because it's much simpler to do thing with pixels than calculate.

Answer (score 0):

`.em`'s are relative measurements, not absolute.